# Specs2 sequential keyword

Tags: scala, testing, specs2

When I run tests in Junit, their ordering isn't guaranteed. By default, specs2 runs the examples in parallel so ordering isn't guaranteed here as well. However, if I add the sequential keyword, the tests are executed (at least from what it seems) in order. Is there a way to get the sequential behavior but have the examples run in random order?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the latest specs2 2.3-SNAPSHOT version with the `random` command-line argument (or `args.execute(random=true)` inside the specification):

```
class TestSpec extends Specification { def is = s2"""

  test1 $e1
  test2 $e2
  test3 $e3

  """

  def e1 = { "starting e1".pp; Thread.sleep(30); "e1".pp; ok }
  def e2 = { "starting e2".pp; Thread.sleep(20); "e2".pp; ok }
  def e3 = { "starting e3".pp; Thread.sleep(40); "e3".pp; ok }
}

sbt> testOnly *TestSpec* -- random

starting e3
e3
starting e2
e2
starting e1
e1
[info] TestSpec
[info]
[info]   + test1
[info]   + test2
[info]   + test3
[info]
```

Comment: what about for mutable Specification

Comment: more specifically, mutable.SpecificationWithJUnit

Comment: I'm not running the test via sbt but rather via maven/surefire/junit/specs2

Answer (score 0):

How about decorating/wrapping the test cases with code that acquires a lock at the beginning of each test case? Hacky perhaps, but should work reliably and be easy to implement, until/unless you can find a more meant-to-be-used alternative.

Comment: I'm wondering if the library offers something like this not how to do it.

Comment: there's no facility in specs2 to do this but I could add a "hook" to the sbt runner to allow you to run with any `Reporter`. Then you could override the `ExecutionStrategy` trait which executes examples so that they are executed randomly. Another approach would be for you to generate the tests from a method that would scramble them on each run.

Comment: The thing is I want to create a standard because I don't want developers writing tests that depend on ordering. It would be nice if there was a keyword like sequential where the tests would run one at time but at no particular order (like in junit).